# Transform an array into a string inline

Tags: c#, arrays, anonymous-function

What is the tersest way to transform an integer array into a string enumerating the elements inline? I'm thinking something like an anonymous function that performs the conversion.

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2 }
var s = string.Format("{0}", 
                      new [] 
                      { /*inline transform array into the string "1, 2"*/ });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx). In .NET 3.5 and earlier you need to convert to a string array first; in .NET 4 there's an overload taking `IEnumerable<T>`. So depending on your version:

.NET 2.0 or 3.0 / C# 2:

```
string s = string.Join(", ",
    Array.ConvertAll(delegate(int x) { return x.ToString(); });
```

.NET 2.0 or 3.0 / C# 3:

```
string s = string.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString());
```

.NET 3.5 / C# 3:

```
string s = string.Join(", ", array.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

(or use the version which works with .NET 2.0 if you prefer).

.NET 4:

```
string s = string.Join(", ", array);
```

(I hadn't even seen that before today!)

Answer (score 3):

With String.Join, for .NET 4.0:

```
var s = String.Join(", ",array);
```

This works because String.Join now has a overload that takes IEnumerable<T>,

For 3.5, you can use

```
var s = String.Join(", ", array.Select(n => n.ToString()).ToArray());
```

For previous .NET versions, see Jon Skeets more complete answer.

Comment: @Jon - Wouldn't it use the `Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)` overload?

Comment: +1 - I didn't expect that to work. Doh... hadn't seen the `IEnumerable<T>` overload (new to .NET 4).

Comment: @Jon Thanks, I edited back to the orignal answer; after I confirmed it with my  trusty compiler :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .Net 4:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 2 };
var s = String.Join(", ", array);
```

There was a [`String.Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) overloaded added :)

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper gives me something like:

```
    public static string EnumerateToString(this int[] a, string separator)
    {
        return a.Aggregate("", (current, i) => current + i.ToString(separator));
    }
```

Comment: That will potentially get very slow, as it will be copying the string on every iteration. Basically you end up with O(n^2) complexity.